# Prove that the infinite unordered sum $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} 2^{-|i|}$ converges to $3$ by definition. Stuck on last part.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

We're using the definition and we're doing the proof from pages 113-114, *Elementary Real Analysis* by Bruckner et. al.

The definition is:
[image]

The proof requires that we show that $\left \lvert \sum_{-N \leq i \leq N} 2^{-|i|} - 3 \right \lvert< \epsilon/2$, which acts as the sum from the $I_0$ set, and that we also show the sum which extends it is also such that $\sum_{i \in J/ I_0} 2^{-|i|} < \epsilon/2$. Then we get:

$$\left \lvert \sum_{i \in J} 2^{-|i|} -3 \right \lvert = \left \vert \sum_{-N \leq i \leq N} 2^{-|i|} - 3 \right \lvert + \sum_{i \in J / I_0} 2^{-|i|} < \epsilon$$

which satisfies the definition.

First, we show, using properties of geometric sums,  $$\left \lvert \sum_{-N \leq i \leq N} 2^{-|i|} - 3 \right \lvert = 2(2^{-N})< \epsilon/2$$

And now I've gotten stuck at the next  part, show that $\sum_{i \in J/ I_0} 2^{-|i|} < \epsilon/2$. Now, I'm able to prove the statement only by assuming a certain structure, which prevents me from concluding about an unordered sum. **My question is**, how do I prove it without assuming such structure, or how do I prove for whatever structure the sum might have so that it holds for the unordered sum?

Here's my attempt, making some assumptions about the structure of the sum:

Suppose a finite $K \subset \mathbb{Z}$ with it's elements satisfying $|k| > N$. (What follows is the assumptions I need to get rid of:) We suppose $K$ has size $\|K\|$, and suppose there is an identical number of positive and negative elements, and so by letting $\beta := \frac{\|K\|}{2}$, we can write:
$$2^{-|-N-\beta|} + \cdots + 2^{-|-N-1|}+2^{-(N+1)}+\cdots+2^{-(N+\beta)}$$
which is identical to:
$$2^{-(N+\beta)} + \cdots + 2^{-(N+1)}+2^{-(N+1)}+\cdots+2^{-(N+\beta)}$$
so we can do:
$$=2(2^{-(N+1)}+\cdots+2^{-(N+\beta)})$$
$$=2\cdot2^{-N}(2^{-1}+\cdots+2^{-\beta})$$

using the properties of geometric sums:

$$=2^{-N+1}\left(\frac{-1+2^{-\beta}}{1-2}\right)$$
$$=2^{-N+1} - 2^{-\beta}$$

From which we get that it is smaller than $2(2^{-N})$, and so smaller than $\epsilon/2$, which allows us to complete the proof.

But of course, we can't do that since there are other possibilities for the structure of the $\sum_{i \in J/ I_0} 2^{-|i|}$, e.g., an uneven number of positive elements and negative elements. I would need to somehow show that all of these are smaller than the one I've chosen, or something along those lines. Does anyone have suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Just a remark: If you know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n} = 1$, the result is immediate since $\sum_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}2^{-|i|} = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}+ 2^{0}$.

Comment: @IamWill thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=max_{i\in J}\,|i|$. Then $\sum_{i\in J\setminus I_0}2^{-|i|}\le\sum_{N<|i|\le M}2^{-|i|}$, which you know how to compute.

Comment: Thanks for the help!